# Colouring three individual attributes in point layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, color, expression

I am new to QGIS and am learning the expressions function. I would like to know how to independently colour three separate attributes on a point layer as below:
[image: Map image]

Answer (score 2):

You want to colour the feature labels. I think it is not possible to have different formats for parts (lines) of a label.

Try to create three layers, using the same data source. Then you can create three labels, formatting and shifting them as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply different label style rules to a single layer. So there is only one label style availabel for one layer.

A workaround is to duplicate the layer (Right click layer in TOC > Duplicate) as many times as you want different styles. In your case duplicate twice and set the label style for the original layer and the two duplicates.

Under layer properties > label properties > Placement you can set the quadrant and y-offset to get the label placement for each layer.